# Vim 's' Key Broken

Tags: macos, vim, macvim

`s` in command mode normally deletes the character under the cursor and enters Insert mode. But typing `s` now opens a prompt like this (in the lower-left corner)

>

instead of the usual substitution mode.

What I checked:

- No keys are being remapped in .vimrc
- `:map s` shows:

```
    x  s             <Plug>Sneak_s
    n  s             <Plug>Sneak_s
```

Is that remapping x-s or s?

## What could cause this behavior?

Edit: I am using the vundle plugin manager. And removing this line from .vimrc solves the problem.

```
call vundle#end()
```

## Isn't that required?

Edit 2: As @yolenoyer notes, the vundle#end() is required, or *all* plugins are disabled. Using that advice, narrows it down to the vim-sneak plugin which even says in it's documentation:

> [How dare you remap s](https://github.com/justinmk/vim-sneak)?

Comment: There is no mode called substitution in vim and command mode do you mean command-line mode or normal mode ? Please be more specific !

Comment: Thank you for your comment. There are two modes in vi: command and insert mode. I believe you're thinking of command mode as "normal" mode.

Comment: There is more than 2 modes in vi.

Comment: Ah, yes, of course - the last-line mode invoked by ':'  - Is that what you meant by "command-line mode"?

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I don't see any other way than mapping to alter the behaviour of `s` normal command.
  Are you *really* sure there's no mapping? Please check again your mappings, by running the following command:

  ```
  :map s
  ```
- Don't remove the `call vundle#end()` line in your `.vimrc` : it will disable all the plugins you installed.

  Instead, try to comment each plugin listed just before this line (lines beginning with `Plugin`), each time launching vim again to check if the behaviour changed.

#### Some clarification about modes

When you type `s` in normal mode, you don't enter in any 'substitution' mode, but in **insert** 
mode after having deleted one (or more) char(s) in front of the cursor.

The confusion you make by using the word 'substitution' (in your title and your question content) is 
problematic because it makes people think you're talking about the `:s` command (which can be really 
called ... the substitute command!)

Comment: Excellent. I wasn't finding the problem initially, because as you say, removing vundle#end() was disabling _all_ plugins! Following your advice, I narrowed it down to the vim-sneak plugin, which had remapped the `s` key.

Answer (score 0):

Vim's search and replace (substitute) does not require any additional module or mapping in `.vimrc`. You can simply use `:%s/foo/bar/g` to replace any instance of `foo` with `bar`. For more information checkout [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace).

Note that substitute command `s` without `:` (normal command) which may be prefixed with a number `x`, deletes `x` characters and switches to insert mode.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer! This happens in *command* mode. That is, not on the prompt you get when you type colon-s (:s/pat/repl/).

Comment: @automorphic There are normal, insert and visual modes. Could you kindly elaborate what you mean by the command mode?

Comment: Command mode is what you call normal mode. The one where the navigation keys h,j,k,l move the cursor (and `s` enters substitution mode).

Comment: Yes, the second mode you mention. That is broken if my .vimrc calls `vundle#end()`.